# update-values not generating an actual update on hsqldb

Tags: clojure, hsqldb

I'm new to clojure. Have been playing with jdbc using hsqldb.

Did this function to update table "persona" where the field "cedula" is the primary key

```
(defn update [cedula x]
(sql/with-connection common/database
    (sql/update-values :persona
        ["cedula=?" cedula] x)))
```

Ran this in REPL

```
(per/update 111 {:cedula 122 :nombre "Raul" :cargo "mm"})
```

But after that if I go to the .log file in the DB I see that it does a delete and then an insert.

```
/*C15*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CONNECT USER SA
SET AUTOCOMMIT FALSE
DELETE FROM PERSONA WHERE CEDULA=111
INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES(122,'Raul','mm')
COMMIT
SET AUTOCOMMIT TRUE
DISCONNECT
```

Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code for `update-values`:

```
(defn update-values
  "Updates values on selected rows in a table. where-params is a vector
  containing a string providing the (optionally parameterized) selection
  criteria followed by values for any parameters. record is a map from
  strings or keywords (identifying columns) to updated values."
  [table where-params record]
  (let [[where & params] where-params
        column-strs (map as-identifier (keys record))
        columns (apply str (concat (interpose "=?, " column-strs) "=?"))]
    (do-prepared
      (format "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s"
              (as-identifier table) columns where)
      (concat (vals record) params))))
```

As you can see, there's absolutely no way it will generate anything but a UPDATE, as it ought to. So what's actually happening?

[From the HSQLDB docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_app_dev_testing):

> As HyperSQL logs the DDL and DML statements in the .log file, this file can be used to check what is being sent to the database. **Note that UPDATE statements are represented by a DELETE followed by an INSERT statement.**

So the HSQLDB log is simply writing a DELETE and INSERT, even though the query being executed is really an UPDATE.